# Binding string field from child to parent component not working

Tags: angularjs, binding, angular, components, parent-child

There example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQKkfs?p=preview) show pretty simple page where we have one parent component and one child component. From parent to child we pass two values, one of them is string and another one is array.

```
<child [aList]="sharedList" [aString]="sharedString"></child>
```

Problem is when i'm update the string value it updates in child component only but not in parent. But if i update array value from child component it will be updated in both (child and parent).

So my question is why string value does not updated in parent from child but array value does. What i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript primitive types (strings, numbers, etc.) are *immutable*. Objects (complex types like arrays, objects, functions, etc.) are mutable and passed by reference. It means that when you pass a string from parent into child, you really pass a *copy* of the value, i.e. another string.

When you later change primitive value in child, the original one parent holds is not going to update automatically.

Whilst, when you pass an object (like array), parent and child both going to work with the reference to the same object. Changes to one are reflected in another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realise that from plain JavaScript view but in first angular we can write something like this `<some-directive myValue="mySharedObject.stringValue"/>` and after we change this value in directive this will be changed controller. Maybe ask a wrong question (sorry about that), my real question is how implement this in Angular 2. I update plunk for more similarity to my problem.